# Cloning a local Git repo into Cloud-based Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, cloud, devops

I'm putting together a simple cloud-based Azure DevOps-based pipeline as a proof-of-concept.

I want to import a Git repo from my local machine into an Azure-based Git repo.

I'm not looking to sync the repos as this is only a PoC.

I'm a new to Azure and only have limited Jenkins/Git experience.

How do I go about this?

Thanks in advance

PS - I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.8.1

Comment: I didn't understand, you want to push your local git repo into Azdo git?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have a git repo on my local machine that contains a demo. I can build and run that locally from Visual Studio using Cmake. I'm putting together a proof-of-concept in our new Azure tenancy and I want to use the same code to put a Azure Devops pipeline together to demonstrate Azure capabilities. This particular demo is an example of some of our software engineering capabilties and is well-known within our company. I'm more of a manager and my hands-on skills are very rusty. My main DevOps guy is off ill, so I'm having to do it myself!

Comment: Ok, Got it. take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65367654/how-to-push-my-code-from-local-machine-to-azure-devops-in-a-different-branch-oth in order to push your local repository to the remote repository. focus on the "A quick git tutorial" part.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try the code in that link, I get the impression that it thinks I'm tryng to push an Azure repo into my local repo - I need to do the exact opposite!

Comment: see my answer for further information about last comment.

Answer (score 0):

"Cloning a local Git repo into Cloud-based Azure DevOps",

**What you actually mean is pushing local files into the remote repository.**

---

Based on our conversation in the comments,
Follow those few steps to push the code to the remote repository:

1. Create a Azure Devops Repository (If Repository already exists, skip this)
2. On your local repository (in your IDE terminal) `git init` to initialize a git repo.

   2.1   If a local git repo already initialized on your filesystem (`.git` directory exists) use `git remote -v` to verify the remote. output :

```
azure   https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_git/repository (fetch)
azure   https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_git/repository (push)
```

3. add all files to the staging area `git add .`
4. Record the changes made to the files in the staging area `git commit -m "<some commit message>"`
5. upload local repository commits to a remote repository `git push -u origin <branch_name>`